# How do I set an HTML class attribute in Markdown?

Tags: html, markdown

If I have some Markdown like

```
## My Title

A paragraph of content here.

    code_line(1);
    // a code comment
    class MoreCode { }

and more text to follow...
```

How can I set a class on the `<code>` block that's generated in the middle there? I want to have it output

```
<code class=’prettyprint’>
  code_line(1);
  // a code comment
  class More Code { }
</code>
```

But I can't seem to set it. I do *not* have control over the Markdown code being run, only over the content.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can [embed HTML in Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html). Type literally what you want, with no indent.

```
<code class="prettyprint">
  code_line(1);
  // a code comment
  class More Code { }
</code>
```

For the specific case of [syntax highlighting](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#syntax-highlighting) following the back ticks at the start of a fenced code block with the language works just about everywhere these days.

````
```js
code_line(1);
// a code comment
class MoreCode { }
```
````

Comment: Alas, I suspected this was the only option. Glad to have some confirmation.

Answer (score 24):

Though not answering the question exactly. You can use a different render too like Maruku or Kramdown:

```
## My Title

A paragraph of content here.
~~~
code_line(1);
// a code comment
class MoreCode { }
~~~
{: .prettyprint}

and more text to follow...
```

Output (tested with haml & kramdown):

```
<pre class="prettyprint"><code>
code_line(1);
// a code comment
class MoreCode { }
</code></pre>
```

Kramdown syntax: http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/quickref.html#block-attributes

Comment: +1 for Multimarkdown and Kramdown. Definition lists, tables and much, much more :-)

Comment: Note that Kramdown is the default parser in Jekyll, so you can just start using this without installing anything if Jekyll is your static site builder.

Answer (score 4):

Markdown has an extension ([attr_list.py](http://web.archive.org/web/20130315222028/https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/attr_list.html)) which allows you to use Maruku's `{: .classname}` syntax.

Comment: Thanks. Would be even better answer if you included some links.

Answer (score 4):

Markdown Extra supports class and id attributes using curly braces. See: https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#spe-attr

Comment: Also available in [markdown-it-attrs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it-attrs) if you are in a JS-environment