# Can I define a class name on paragraph using Markdown?

Tags: css, markdown

Can I define a class name on paragraph using Markdown? If so, how?

Comment: [Biased] If you happen to be a Node user, please check out [Rho](http://npmjs.org/package/rho). Although it's not 100% compatible with Markdown, you may still find it very attractive, since it has the feature you require at its core.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Dupe: [How do I set an HTML class attribute in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975264/how-do-i-set-an-html-class-attribute-in-markdown)

---

### Natively? No. But...

No, Markdown's syntax can't. You can [set ID values](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/#header-id) with Markdown Extra through.

You can [use regular HTML](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/#html) if you like, and add the attribute [`markdown="1"`](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/#markdown-attr) to continue markdown-conversion within the HTML element. This requires [Markdown Extra](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/) though.

```
<p class='specialParagraph' markdown='1'>
**Another paragraph** which allows *Markdown* within it.
</p>
```

### Possible Solution: (Untested and intended for `<blockquote>`)

I found the following online:

*Function*

```
function _DoBlockQuotes_callback($matches) {

    ...cut...

    //add id and class details...
    $id = $class = '';
    if(preg_match_all('/\{(?:([#.][-_:a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)+)\}/',$bq,$matches)) {
        foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
            if($match[0]=='#') $type = 'id';
            else $type = 'class';
            ${$type} = ' '.$type.'="'.trim($match,'.# ').'"';
        }
        foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
            $bq = str_replace($match,'',$bq);
        }
    }

    return _HashBlock(
        "<blockquote{$id}{$class}>\n$bq\n</blockquote>"
    ) . "\n\n";
}
```

*Markdown*

```
>{.className}{#id}This is the blockquote
```

*Result*

```
<blockquote id="id" class="className">
    <p>This is the blockquote</p>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: (Tested with MaRuKu parser) you can use just "{.class-name}" at the start of a line of text to effect the P tag. The id part is ignored however.

Answer (score 85):

Raw HTML is actually perfectly valid in markdown.  For instance:

```
Normal *markdown* paragraph.

<p class="myclass">This paragraph has a class "myclass"</p>
```

Just make sure the HTML is not inside a code block.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the inner text is no longer markdown.

Comment: @akauppi Yes; this can be gotten around with using a span tag, though.

Comment: @Seraphendipity Not on my MD editor. I guess it depends on the editor

Answer (score 22):

If your environment is JavaScript, use [markdown-it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it) along with the plugin [markdown-it-attrs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it-attrs):

```
const md = require('markdown-it')();
const attrs = require('markdown-it-attrs');
md.use(attrs);

const src = 'paragraph {.className #id and=attributes}';

// render
let res = md.render(src);
console.log(res);
```

**Output**

```
<p class="className" id="id" and="attributes">paragraph</p>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anr53236/)

**Note:** Be aware of the security aspect when allowing attributes in your markdown!

Disclaimer, I'm the author of markdown-it-attrs.

Comment: Markdown It Rocks!!

Answer (score 13):

If your flavour of markdown is kramdown, then you can set css class like this:

```
{:.nameofclass}
paragraph is here
```

Then in you css file, you set the css like this:

```
.nameofclass{
   color: #000;
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

Markdown *should* have this capability, but it doesn't. Instead, you're stuck with language-specific Markdown supersets:

**PHP:** [Markdown Extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#spe-attr)
**Ruby:** [Kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/), [Maruku](http://maruku.rubyforge.org/)

But if you need to abide by true Markdown syntax, you're stuck with inserting raw HTML, which is less ideal.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a working example for kramdown following @Yarin's answer.

```
A simple paragraph with a class attribute.
{:.yourClass}
```

Reference: https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#inline-attribute-lists

Comment: I had no idea about this. Works pretty well with [Markdown Preview (Sublime 3)](https://github.com/revolunet/sublimetext-markdown-preview) that uses the builtin `Python` `Markdown` parser.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above markdown itself leaves you hanging on this.  However, depending on the implementation there are some workarounds:

At least one version of MD considers `<div>` to be a block level tag but `<DIV>` is just text.  All broswers however are case insensitive.  This allows you to keep the syntax simplicity of MD, at the cost of adding div container tags.

So the following is a workaround:

```
<DIV class=foo>

  Paragraphs here inherit class foo from above.

</div>
```

The downside of this is that the output code has `<p>` tags wrapping the `<div>` lines (both of them, the first because it's not  and the second because it doesn't match.  No browser fusses about this that I've found, but the code won't validate.  MD tends to put in spare `<p>` tags anyway.

Several versions of markdown implement the convention `<tag markdown="1">` in which case MD will do the normal processing inside the tag.  The above example becomes:

```
<div markdown="1" class=foo>

  Paragraphs here inherit class foo from above.

</div>
```

The current version of Fletcher's *MultiMarkdown* allows attributes to follow the link if using referenced links.

Comment: Note: Please make sure you use code markers; most of this post was hidden since it was interpreted as HTML tags.

Comment: Thanks - the DIV hack is the only answer here that seems to work with pegdown / cegdown.  (Pegdown is also extensible with plugins, so I might do that in the longer run)

Answer (score 2):

In **slim markdown** use this:

```
markdown:
  {:.cool-heading}
  #Some Title
```

Translates to:

```
<h1 class="cool-heading">Some Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

It should also be mentioned that `<span>` tags allow inside them -- block-level items negate MD natively inside them unless you configure them not to do so, but in-line styles natively allow MD within them. As such, I often do something akin to...

```
This is a superfluous paragraph thing.

<span class="class-red">And thus I delve into my topic, Lorem ipsum lollipop bubblegum.</span>

And thus with that I conclude.
```

I am not 100% sure if this is universal but seems to be the case in all MD editors I've used.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a selector for Javascript purposes (like I did), you might just want to use a `href` attribute instead of a `class` or `id`:

Just do this:

```
<a href="#foo">Link</a>
```

Markdown will not ignore or remove the `href` attribute like it does with classes and ids.

So in your Javascript or jQuery you can then do:

```
$('a[href$="foo"]').click(function(event) {

    ... do your thing ...

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

At least this works in my version of Markdown...