# Attach class to :markdown paragraph in Haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, markdown

I don't want the extra wrapping div that the following provides:

```
.note
  :markdown
    Please, [don't use Haml for markup][x], for your sake!
    [x]: http://chriseppstein.github.com/blog/2010/02/08/haml-sucks-for-content/
```

But I do not want to have to write this:

```
%p.note
  Please,
  = link_to("don't use Haml for markup", "http://chriseppstein.github.com/blog/2010/02/08/haml-sucks-for-content/") + ", for your sake!"
```

Is there a way to use `:markdown` but also attach a CSS class to the generated paragraph tag?

See: http://chriseppstein.github.com/blog/2010/02/08/haml-sucks-for-content/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer appears to be: [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058933/can-i-define-a-class-name-on-paragraph-using-markdown). This is a Markdown issue, not a HAML issue.

You can do it though just by using HTML directly in the `markdown` block:

```
:markdown
  <p class="note">
    some more HTML
  </p>
```

But you can't stick markdown inside the tags, because everthing in there is interpreted as HTML and not Markdown. There may be extensions that allow you to add classes like this, but it's apparently not possible natively.

Comment: That won't actually achieve the desired effect, because the `:markdown` filter creates an extra `<p>` wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found of doing this involves using the Maruku filter (you may need the haml-contrib gem for that), because Maruku implements the [PHP Markdown Extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/) extensions to standard Markdown. That makes a lot of neat stuff possible, including specifying Markdown parsing within an enclosing block element with `markdown='1'`, so you can do

```haml
:maruku
  <p class='note' markdown='1'>
    Please, [don't use Haml for markup][x], for your sake!
  </p>  
  [x]: http://chriseppstein.github.com/blog/2010/02/08/haml-sucks-for-content/
```

which becomes

```html
<p class='note'>Please, <a href='http://chriseppstein.github.com/blog/2010/02/08/haml-sucks-for-content/'>don&#8217;t use Haml for markup</a>, for your sake!</p>
```

(yes, the link ref needs to come after the `</p>` in this case.)

Note that Maruku doesn't insert an extra wrapper element in this case.

Putting classes on other elements with this syntax is even easier:

```markdown
:maruku
  # Cool stuff {#cool_stuff}

  You can put classes and IDs on [links](links.html){.links} too.
```

becomes

```html
<h1 id='cool_stuff'>Cool stuff</h1>

<p>You can put classes and IDs on <a class='links' href='links.html'>links</a> too.</p>
```