# Separating code from content in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm using Jekyll to re-develop my blog and I'm getting a bit stuck with code blocks.

I've got them rendering out in `.highlight` divs, but I want the rest of the content to be wrapped in a `.content` div. It's a little hard to explain so I'll show you.

Here is what I'm getting:

```
<article>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <div class="highlight">
        <pre><code>
        // Code example
        </code></pre>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, at.</p>
</article>
```

Here's what I want to get:

```
<article>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="highlight">
        <pre><code>
        // Code example
        </code></pre>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, at.</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

I know it's possible because it's [been done before](http://aerotwist.com/blog/css-triggers/), I just can't figure out how. I could put the classes as HTML in the markdown file, but that feels a bit hacky.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I define a class name on paragraph using Markdown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058933/can-i-define-a-class-name-on-paragraph-using-markdown)

Comment: Not quite, most of the answers there are about adding HTML to your markdown file which is what I don't want to do.