# How to add class attribute for table element which parsedown gives?

Tags: php, laravel, parsedown

I have some markdown files and I want to display them on my blog which developed by Laravel.

So I think out such a solution:

#### Controller

```
public function display() {
    $pd = new Parsedown();
    $text = Storage::disk('local')->get('x.md');
    $html = $pd->text($text);
    $title = "title";
    return view('x.y', [
        "html" => $html,
        "title" => $title
    ]);
}
```

#### Blade

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title text-center">{{ $title }}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                {!! $html !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

It works well except `table` element:

`Parsedown` parse table like that:

```
header 1 | header 2
-------- | --------
cell 1.1 | cell 1.2
cell 2.1 | cell 2.2
```

into:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>header 1</th>
<th>header 2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>cell 1.1</td>
<td>cell 1.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>cell 2.1</td>
<td>cell 2.2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Then I got a table with no bootstrap styles, and it looks weird. What I want to get is:

```
<table class="table">
  ...
</table>
```

So, could anyone please give me some suggestions about that?

Comment: This might be related to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058933/can-i-define-a-class-name-on-paragraph-using-markdown

Comment: Heve you tried [parsedown-extra](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown-extra)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I read the source code of Parsedown, I find a solution.

In `blockTable()` method:

change this:

```
        $Block = array(
            'alignments' => $alignments,
            'identified' => true,
            'element' => array(
                'name' => 'table',
                'handler' => 'elements'
            ),
        );
```

to:

```
        $Block = array(
            'alignments' => $alignments,
            'identified' => true,
            'element' => array(
                'name' => 'table',
                'handler' => 'elements',
                'attributes' => [       //+
                    "class" => "table"  //+
                ]                       //+
            ),
        );
```

And it will output `table` element with `class="table"`.

Finally, I created a new class which extends `Parsedown`, and override that `blockTable` method with my own implementation.

Comment: Ah, the nice thing about Open-Source: change it to suit your needs! +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

[`Parsedown`](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown) does not support adding `class` to generated elements. `Parsedown` also does not support emitting the generated HTML as an XML document. Therefore, you have two choices:

1. Use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace with regular expressions.
2. Use [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) (or similar) to parse the HTML tree and replace elements.

Since the HTML `Parsedown` generates is simple, well-formed, and predictable you can *probably* get away with `preg_replace`. The implementation would look something like this:

```
public function display() {
    $pd = new Parsedown();
    $text = Storage::disk('local')->get('x.md');
    $html = $pd->text($text);
    $html = preg_replace('/^\s*<table>\s*$/', '<table class="table">', $html);
    $title = "title";
    return view('x.y', [
        "html" => $html,
        "title" => $title
    ]);
}
```

Comment: It works, but I found  a more neat way to achieve this. See my answer.