# Adding a class attribute to a hyperlink in Markdown

Tags: syntax, hyperlink, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set an HTML class attribute in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975264/how-do-i-set-an-html-class-attribute-in-markdown)

In my original link done in plain HTML I have a class attribute like so:

```
<a href="http://example.com" class="noborder">my link</a>
```

How do I translate it to Markdown? I don't know how to put the class in.

```
[mylink](http://example.com)
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't put a class into Markdown syntax. In most Markdown implementations you can embed HTML, so using your original HTML might work.

John Gruber (creator of Markdown) even does it this way:

http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax.text

Comment: knowing that we can embed HTML in most markdown implementations is a huge help!

Comment: Using my original HTML inside the markdown worked for me.

Answer (score 49):

Brian is right.  The standard Markdown dialect does not let you add classes, attributes, or ids to elements.  That said, there are other dialects such as [Maruku](http://maruku.rubyforge.org/index.html) that do you give this sort of flexibility by introducing a meta-data syntax.  Here's a couple example of what it looks like:

```
## A header with an id  ##  {: #the-head}
// => <h2 id="the-head">A header with an id</h2>

[a special url](/my-special-place.html){: .special}
// => <a href="/my-special-place.html" class="special">a special url</a>

A paragraph with a random attribute
{: random=attribute}
// => <p random="attribute">A paragraph with a random attribute</p>
```

For more information check out the Maruku [meta-data proposal](http://maruku.rubyforge.org/proposal.html).

Comment: Also valid for **kramdown** (default for jekyll(http://jekyllrb.com))

Comment: Also check out the plugins available for [markdown-it](http://markdown-it.github.io): [attrs](https://github.com/arve0/markdown-it-attrs) and [decorate](https://github.com/rstacruz/markdown-it-decorate).

Comment: To clarify Alisso's comment, **kramdown** allows you to do it just like Maraku does. [Here](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#attribute-list-definitions) is the related bit from documentation.