# python markdown extension for add class

Tags: python, markdown

is there a python markdown extension for add class for a tag such as

example:

```
<a>name</a>
```

will be markdown as:

```
<a class="a_style">name</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass class attribute and value to markdown syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853620/how-to-pass-class-attribute-and-value-to-markdown-syntax)

Comment: I'm confused by your example, is <a>name</a> the input and <a class="a_style">name</a> your output? Would you be interested in writing an extension or are you only interested in extensions that already exist?

Answer (score 0):

In the question of [Get python-markdown extension to output html tags with a specific class attribute in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986784/get-python-markdown-extension-to-output-html-tags-with-a-specific-class-attribut), I give code for a python-markdown extension that can add HTML attributes.