# Get python-markdown extension to output html tags with a specific class attribute in Django?

Tags: python, django, markdown

I initially thought that [how to pass class attribute and value to markdown syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853620/how-to-pass-class-attribute-and-value-to-markdown-syntax) and [How do I set an HTML class attribute in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975264/how-do-i-set-an-html-class-attribute-in-markdown) asked the question that I want to ask here, but I want to know how to write an python-markdown **extension** that outputs an html span element with specific class attribute in Django.

I've written the following extension (file saved as "mdx_debatesyntax.py"):

```
import markdown
from markdown.inlinepatterns import Pattern

PREMISE_RE = r'(\[p )(.*?)\]'

class AttrTagPattern(Pattern):
    """
    Return element of type `tag` with a text attribute of group(3) 
    of a Pattern and with the html attributes defined with the constructor.

    """
    def __init__ (self, pattern, tag, attrs):
        Pattern.__init__(self, pattern)
        self.tag = tag
        self.attrs = attrs

    def handleMatch(self, m):
        el = markdown.util.etree.Element(self.tag)
        el.text = m.group(3)
        for (key,val) in self.attrs.items():
            el.set(key,val)
        return el

class DebateSyntaxExtension(markdown.Extension):
    def extendMarkdown(self, md, md_globals):
        premise_tag = AttrTagPattern(PREMISE_RE, 'span',{'class':'premise'})
        md.inlinePatterns.add('premise', premise_tag, '_begin')

def makeExtension(configs=None):
    return DebateSyntaxExtension(configs=configs)
```

And when I test this directly (not through Django) it works:

```
import markdown
md = markdown.Markdown(extensions=['debatesyntax'])
md.convert('This is a [p test]!')
```

Returns

```
u'<p>This is a <span class="premise">test</span>!</p>'
```

However, when I run this through Django, the attribute class gets stripped, giving me:

```
<p>This is a <span>test</span>!</p>
```

How do I prevent the class attribute (or other attributes) from being stripped?

**Resolution**

The Django app that I was modifying (OSQA), was manually "sanitizing" the HTML. The AttrTagPattern class code does, after all, work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
{{ value|markdown:"debatesyntax" }}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is this a modification to the extension that I'm writing?

Comment: @Jonathan I mean that have you tried using your markdown extension in template as such way?