# Jekyll Blog Post: Centering Images

Tags: css, styling

Say you have a blog site with Jekyll and the blog posts are centered on the page. I want content (i.e. paragraphs, words, code, etc.) to be aligned to the left, but images to be centered.

I have the text, etc. left-aligned, but now I'm struggling to get the image (who has a CSS style of `max-height: 80%`) to be centered as well.

It appears that Jekyll's blog generator (from Markdown) wraps images in `<p></p>` tags so `margin: 0 auto` doesn't center the image. I've attached code snippets below:

```
<li>
    <h2 class="post-title">Hello World</h2>
    <div class="post-date"><span>May 21, 2014</span></div>
    <div class="post-content">
        <p><img src="/images/photos/blog/hello-world.jpg" alt="blog-image"></p>
    </div>
</li>

ul#posts {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
}

ul#posts > li {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul#posts > li div.post-content {
  text-align: left;
}

ul#posts > li > div.post-date {
  color: #A0A0A0;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

ul#posts > li > div.post-content > p > img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 80%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

How can I center the image in the blog post?

Comment: There will be text in other `<p>` tags as well, and I don't want that text to be centered.

Answer (score 39):

Here is a way to do it via kramdown:

```
{:refdef: style="text-align: center;"}
![My Image]({{ site.baseimg }}/images/example1.png)
{: refdef}
```

This will create another paragraph around the paragraph added by kramdown. [Source](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#block-attributes)

Answer (score 13):

### Kramdown

[Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/#kramdown) uses [kramdown](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html) as a default markdown renderer.

`kramdown` allows you to add additional attributes to the original markdown-flavored image link like below. (See [here](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#images) and [here](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#attribute-list-definitions) for the official syntaxes)

If you are interested, you can check out the working example from my [blog post](https://lazyren.github.io/devlog/hydejack-post-writing-tips-tricks.html#center-image)

### Apply attributes directly to the `img`

```markdown
![placeholder](https://via.placeholder.com/100x150){:style="display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto"}
```

Above will print image centered.
[image]

#### Add user-defined css class for easier use

```css
img.centered {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

I personally adds above code to my blog's css file and simply uses like

```markdown
![placeholder](https://via.placeholder.com/100x150){:.centered}
```

It is essentially the same as the first codeblock, but much easier to use.

### Apply attributes to the `<p>` tag

One other way is to apply attributes to the `<p>` tag that surrounds `img`. The advantage of this method is that you can center multiple images (as long as they are on the same paragraph).

```markdown
{:style="text-align:center;"}
![placeholder](https://via.placeholder.com/100x150)
![placeholder](https://via.placeholder.com/100x150)
```

#### Add user-defined css class for easier use

```css
.text-align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Once again you may put above code into your css file and use it like below.

```markdown
{:.text-align-center}
![placeholder](https://via.placeholder.com/100x150)
![placeholder](https://via.placeholder.com/100x150)
```

EDIT: It just crossed my mind if you wants **ALL** image to be centered by default, adding

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

to your css file may works for you. But note that I have not tested deeply enough to find out any unwanted side effects. So use it at your own risk.

Answer (score 5):

I had to do the same in **markdown** on drupal and this solution worked for me though.

I aligned my images to the right by adding inline CSS like this:

```
<div style="text-align: right"><img src="/default/image/sms.png" width="100" /></div>
```

For aligning your image to the right or center, replace

```
<div style="text-align: right">
```

to

```
<div style="text-align: center">
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple code works for me.

```
<p align="center"">
   <img src="/default/image/sample.png" width="100%" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you add `display: block` to your style so that `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right:auto` have the expected effect:

```
ul#posts > li > div.post-content > p > img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 80%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{: style="display:block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you have your image wrapped in a set of p tags you can simply set those p tags to text-align: center; It would most likely be best to give those p tags a class so you don't mess up any other p tags on the page. Hope that helps!

Codepen: http://codepen.io/Travo100/pen/tJCBH

```
<p class="image-center"><img src="/images/photos/blog/hello-world.jpg" alt="blog-image"></p>

.image-center { text-align: center; }
```

Comment: Is there a way to set HTML tag classes in Markdown?

Comment: I wish I could help you there, but I've never used Markdown. You can set classes for HTML elements using jQuery/Javascript.  A how-to tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-css-class-dynamically-in-jquery/

Comment: You can set classes for elements in Markdown, but it depends on which Markdown processor you're using. Here's a SO post about using classes with the Kramdown processor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975264/how-do-i-set-an-html-class-attribute-in-markdown

Comment: And here's a gist showing something similar to your .md and .html files: https://gist.github.com/nicksuch/5c3d6b2da80bd7a3952e

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to achieve horizontal centering

1.

```
.container-to-be-centered {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: "fixed width here"
}
```

2.

```
.parent-container {
  text-align: center;
}
.child-container-to-be-centered {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

3.

```
.container-to-be-centered {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: "negative value of the container width"
}
```

etc.

So in this case to center your image

```
<p>
  <img>
</p>

p {
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way where only paragraphs with `<img>` in them are centered? I don't want every paragraph tag's content to be centered.

Comment: you can wrap a container around **p** tag

**<div class="text-center"><p><img></p></div>**

and use it to center the image instead relying on p to center it