# How to make a styled box (for note/warning/...) in Gitbook?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown, gitbook

Can I somehow create a `<div>` in Gitbook HTML output with a class name described in the markdown. I'd like to do this in order to have information boxes that stand apart from the main text, pretty common in technical literature.

I don't want to embed HTML within the markdown itself, since that evaporates the whole point of using markdown, in the first place.

The [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org) document authoring system seems to have such support built in. Here's a [sample](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html):

`` .. NOTE:: If you are reading this as HTML, please read
   `<cheatsheet.txt>`_ instead to see the input syntax examples! ``

[image]

Note: This is a duplicate of [Can I define a class name on paragraph using Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058933/can-i-define-a-class-name-on-paragraph-using-markdown) and [How do I set an HTML class attribute in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975264/how-do-i-set-an-html-class-attribute-in-markdown)

However, I think I'll leave it here since the focus is a bit above the pure technical. Would like to try out making a gitbook plugin to provide this.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @mzjn. I was hesitant with the Sphinx tag anyways. Now removed.

Comment: The [Admonition Extension](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/admonition.html) for Python-Markdown adds an optional syntax which outputs HTML matching reStructeredText's HTML output. In fact, you can use the same CSS to style it.

Comment: "I don't want to embed HTML within the markdown itself, since that evaporates the whole point of using markdown..." No, it does not, at least not according the its creator. Read the first three paragraphs of the [HTML](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) section of the Syntax rules.

Comment: @Waylan True, but HTML embedding is a one-way street. Some renderers support `markdown="1"` to handle the inner pieces as markdown. This could be a solution to me, but gitbook does not seem to support it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the quotation syntax and editing the CSS to make it look more like a note / warning. For example:

> **Note:**
>
> If you do this bad things may happen.

This is what GitLab does in their [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/account/two_factor_authentication.html).

Comment: Clever. One can probably use the beginning of the quote to differentiate between the different types (note/warning/etc.)